# What is the purpose of SSL in Games

Tags: ssl, encryption

I understand what data encryption is and what role SSL plays in it, but I need to know what role encryption would play in an online game? I have heard many reports of SSL in games, heart-bleed being a popular one, but I just don't see the need for data encryption in games. If something as miniscule as terrain data is being transferred from server to client then what is the need of encryption?

- What role does data encryption play in games?
- What data should and shouldn't be encrypted?
- If encryption is needed, which is better, SSL or TLS? Or are they used for different purposes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) in [game development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) without directly involving programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with games; however, what I know is that both SSL and TLS are used for encryption in web communications. However, SSL is almost [dead](https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf) (at least SSLv3) due to the several attacks it cannot handle.  I don't know if you have lately visit a “https” site which uses SSLv3 using either firefox or chrome but they may say something like this:

Firefox:

```
Unable to Connect Securely

Firefox cannot guarantee the safety of your data on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx because it uses SSLv3, a broken security protocol.
Advanced info: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap
```

Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available
A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol.
Error code: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

So, the answer for your last question should be: Use TLS (TLS 1.2 if possible) instead of SSL. TLS in fact, is basically the evolution of SSL.